# immediately preceding-sibling must contain attribute

Tags: xpath

Here is my XML file:

```
<w type="fruit-hard">apple</w>
<w type="fruit-soft">orange</w>
<w type="vegetable">carrot</w>
```

I need to find carrot's immediately preceding sibling whose type is fruit-soft. In Chrome (locally loaded XML file), when I try

```
$x("//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1]")
```

I get "orange" element node like I want, but how do I require that its type be "fruit-soft"? My attempt (below) returns "false."

```
$x("//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1] and preceding-sibling::w[@type='fruit-soft']")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original XPath ...

```
//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1]
```

... is equivalent to

```
//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[position()=1]
```

.  You can add additional criteria to the predicate as needed:

```
//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[position()=1 and @type='fruit-soft']
```

Or you can add an add a separate predicate

```
//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1][@type='fruit-soft']
```

Note that this attempt:

```
//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1] and preceding-sibling::w[@type='fruit-soft']
```

returns `false` because the parts on either side of the `and` are evaluated separately, converted to type `boolean`, and combined to yield the final result.  Supposing that the context node against which that is evaluated is the document root, there will never be a node matching `preceding-sibling::w[@type='fruit-soft']`.  Moreover, even if there were such a node, that expression does not require nodes matching the first part to be the same ones that matches the second part.

Comment: Thank you. Just before you responded I effectively used your "//w[@type='vegetable']/preceding-sibling::w[1][@type='fruit-soft']" approach and then saw that I was on the right track. Thank you!